# How to make alert sound after adding some data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I want to make an alert sound after adding any new data to the data coming from Firestore.

I'm retrieving some data using streams and streambuilder in a project using Flutter Web, and I want if I added some new data to this collection, it makes an alert sound.

It's not neccessary to make it appear as a notification, just adding this sound after the data updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the soundpool package

https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool/example

You will have to download or create the audio file you would like to play in your alert and add it to the project as an asset